# autoconf ignoring CFLAGS?

Tags: c, gcc, autotools, autoconf

I'm building a package ([vice 3.4](http://vice-emu.sourceforge.net/)) that uses GNU autoconf.  Running `./configure` fails with the following message:

```
checking size of time_t... 0
configure: error: can not figure type of time_t
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.wIgnPw (%build)
```

Examining `config.log`, this appears to be failing due to the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccMTSdtB.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried resolving this by adding `-fPIC` to the `CFLAGS` environment variable:

```
CFLAGS=-fPIC ./configure
```

But while this is clearly being used during other stages of `./configure`...

```
configure:3657: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3679: gcc -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fPIC  -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed  -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld conftest.c  >&5
```

It doesn't seem to be used in the feature tests related to `time_t`:

```
configure:9684: checking for time_t in time.h
configure:9700: gcc -c -g -O3 -Wall -Wformat -Wformat-signedness -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wuninitialized -Wunreachable-code -Wno-unused-parameter -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wfatal-errors  conftest.c >&5
[...]
configure:9753: checking size of time_t
configure:9758: gcc -o conftest -g -O3 -Wall -Wformat -Wformat-signedness -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wuninitialized -Wunreachable-code -Wno-unused-parameter -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wfatal-errors  -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed  -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld conftest.c  >&5
```

Looking at `configure.ac`, the above code is generated from:

```
if test $bu_cv_decl_time_t_time_h = yes; then
  AC_CHECK_SIZEOF([time_t],[],[#include <time.h>])
else
  AC_CHECK_SIZEOF([time_t],[],[#include <sys/types.h>])
fi
```

I've been able to work around the problem by redefining `CC` instead:

```
CC="gcc -fPIC" ./configure
```

This works, but it's ugly (what if something wants to call `gcc` *without* `-fPIC`?). Is there a reason that `AC_CHECK_SIZEOF` is ignoring `CFLAGS`?

Comment: Perhaps the `configure` script modifies `CFLAGS` at some point after the compiler check?  I'm actually more interested in what it's doing to cause the problem to arise in the first place, however.  If you need to patch the build system, then fixing *that* would be what I would consider first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the suspicion I expressed in comments is confirmed.  The VICE configure program intentionally [substitutes its own choice of `CFLAGS` for the user's specified ones](https://sourceforge.net/p/vice-emu/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/vice/configure.proto#l435) when it performs some of its checks, including the ones related to `time_t`.  Thus, this is not a question of *Autoconf* ignoring your flags, but rather of *VICE* doing so.

I reiterate that I think it's a more significant issue that configuration doesn't work out of the box for you in the first place.  I suggest raising that as an issue against the project.  Although I don't like that VICE is so cavalier about ignoring the user's `CFLAGS`, that's a separate matter, and one that I suspect wouldn't get much traction with the devs.

Comment: I've figured out what's going on and posted it as an answer. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

John correctly identified the issue, and based on that information I did a little digging and I've figure out what's going on.

I'm  building this under the control of `rpm`, which calls configure like this:

```
%configure --enable-native-gtk3ui $COMMON_FLAGS
```

That `%configure` expands into a chunk of shell code that looks like this:

```
  CFLAGS="${CFLAGS:--O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection}" ; export CFLAGS ; 
  CXXFLAGS="${CXXFLAGS:--O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection}" ; export CXXFLAGS ; 
  FFLAGS="${FFLAGS:--O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules}" ; export FFLAGS ; 
  FCFLAGS="${FCFLAGS:--O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -I/usr/lib64/gfortran/modules}" ; export FCFLAGS ; 
  LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS:--Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed  -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld}" ; export LDFLAGS; 
  [ "1" = 1 ] && for i in $(find $(dirname ./configure) -name config.guess -o -name config.sub) ; do 
      [ -f /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/$(basename $i) ] && /usr/bin/rm -f $i && /usr/bin/cp -fv /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/$(basename $i) $i ; 
  done ; 
  [ "1" = 1 ] && [ x != "x-Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld" ] && 
      for i in $(find . -name ltmain.sh) ; do 
        /usr/bin/sed -i.backup -e 's~compiler_flags=$~compiler_flags="-Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld"~' $i 
      done ; 
  ./configure --build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu \
    --program-prefix= \
    --disable-dependency-tracking \
     \
    --prefix=/usr \
    --exec-prefix=/usr \
    --bindir=/usr/bin \
    --sbindir=/usr/sbin \
    --sysconfdir=/etc \
    --datadir=/usr/share \
    --includedir=/usr/include \
    --libdir=/usr/lib64 \
    --libexecdir=/usr/libexec \
    --localstatedir=/var \
    --sharedstatedir=/var/lib \
    --mandir=/usr/share/man \
    --infodir=/usr/share/info
```

Of particular interest is the fact that this is setting `LDFLAGS`.  The failing config test is:

```
gcc -o conftest -g -O3 -Wall -Wformat -Wformat-signedness -Wshadow \
  -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wuninitialized -Wunreachable-code \
  -Wno-unused-parameter -Werror=implicit-function-declaration \
  -Wfatal-errors  -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed  -Wl,-z,now \
  -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld conftest.c
```

That `-specs` line points to a gcc spec file that looks like this:

```
*self_spec:
+ %{!static:%{!shared:%{!r:-pie}}}
```

That effectively adds the `-pie` option to the command line.  We can reproduce the failure with a simple `hello.c` program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("hello world\n");
    return(0);
}
```

Like this:

```
$ gcc -o hello -pie hello.c
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccXRAu6r.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But here's the thing:

A *successful* `gcc` invocation looks like this:

```
gcc -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 \
  -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong \
  -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 \
  -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic \
  -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection \
  -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -fPIC  -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed  -Wl,-z,now \
  -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld conftest.c
```

Note that there is a second `-specs` option there, that points to `/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1`, which looks like:

```
*cc1_options:
+ %{!r:%{!fpie:%{!fPIE:%{!fpic:%{!fPIC:%{!fno-pic:-fPIE}}}}}}
```

This takes care of adding `-fPIE` to the command line, which results in a successful compile:

```
$ gcc -o hello -pie -fPIE hello.c
$
```

We're hitting this failure because the `configure` script is *replacing* `CFLAGS` during the tests, but *preserving* `LDFLAGS`. This results in a faulty command line.

For my own purposes, I'm just patching the `configure` script to not replace `CFLAGS` during the `time_t` related tests. This seems both expedient (it's a one-character diff if I just comment out the appropriate line) and effective (it results in a successful build).

I will probably report this upstream as a bug.

Comment: This has been reported upstream as https://sourceforge.net/p/vice-emu/bugs/1188/